# Java duplicate date checking

Tags: java

I try to write the duplicate date checking function in Java but the result is abnormal. Could you please help to check the script any wrong?

```
public boolean DuplicateDate(ExceptGen eg, int dateCount, Ho ho, Date pFromDate, Date pToDate, int d) throws Exception {
    boolean ISDuplicate = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= dateCount; i++) {
        GO go = ho.getGo(i);
        Date fromdate = go.getDate(1);   // Get From Date
        Date todate = go.getDate(2);     // Get To Date 
        if (d != i &&  ((todate.getValue().compareTo(pFromDate.getValue()) != 0 &&
                                pToDate.getValue().compareTo(fromdate.getValue()) != 0))) {
            ISDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ISDuplicate;
}
```

The fail result as follows:

```
  From Date (YYYY-MM-DD)     To Date (YYYY-MM-DD)      
1.  2019/01/01                  2019/01/06

2.  2019/01/06                  2019/01/12

3.  2019/01/12                  2019/01/13
```

The problem as No#1 and No#3 path to show the duplicate record.

Comment: There is a `java.util.Date#equals` that checks if two `Date` are equal based on their millisecond difference.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the case, please give some comments to me. Many Thanks!

Comment: How is it a duplicate if both dates are _not_ equal? Besides that you don't show how you're using that method, e.g. what is `d`, what are the dates you're passing etc. - it would probably be best if _you'd_ step through your code with a debugger and check what goes wrong and where. Additionally, I also don't understand your example, I can't see a real duplicate there.

Comment: Even worse: these are not `java.util.Date` objects because that doesn't have a `getValue()` method.

Comment: My result: 

    From Date     To Date 
1. 2019/01/01    2019/01/06
2. 2019/01/07    2019/01/12

The date checking must be equal to No.1 Then, the result is normal. But I add more record, the result is fail. 

     From Date     To Date 
1. 2019/01/01    2019/01/06
2. 2019/01/07    2019/01/12
3. 2019/01/12    2019/01/14 

Now, the date checking to identify the pattern 1 and  pattern 3 is wrong but I expect the case is correct.

Comment: Completely unclear what you're asking.Unclear what `Date` objects you're working with. Unclear what a `Ho` and a `GO` is. Unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, @BenLee, for providing more information. Please always do that *in the question itself*, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57986391/edit) link, so we have everything in one place. Thank you.

Comment: Also if you could [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please? I believe that it would bring a lot more clarity and probably enable us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `java.util.Date` contains `milliseconds` from the day in the past. To correctly compare that two `Date` is in *same day*, then you have to remove time part of the `Date`:

```
public static boolean isSameDay(Date one, Date two) {
    LocalDate oneLocalDate = one.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate twoLocalDate = two.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    return oneLocalDate.isEqual(twoLocalDate);
}
```

This is one of the possible ways. Main idea is that `Date = <date_part> + <time_part_up_to_milliseconds>`. So when you compare tow `Date` with equals, then it will be `true` only if these dates are in the exactly the same millisecond.

Comment: *"That's becase `Date` contains `milliseconds` from one day in the past."* So you know what `Date` class OP is using?

Comment: Yes, I know. This information does not relate to the question. Main info is that `Date` contains not only date part, but time part as well.

Comment: a `java.sql.Date` has (should have) the time part set to zero; an user implemented `Date` could be  anything; and neither standard `Date` class have a `getValue()` used in question code (could also be wrong); but this seems to be returning a standard `Date`, so the answer is still valid